# Fire & Forget integration pattern

Tags: integration

Started reading '[Integration patterns and practices](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.integration_patterns_and_practices.meta/integration_patterns_and_practices/integ_pat_intro_overview.htm)' and facing some doubts, especially for fire & forget pattern

1. Salesforce has mentioned Platform events as most 'fit' solution for fire & forget pattern. Does that include 'Change data capture' & streaming API, or not as It is not clearly mentioned in the doc. If Streaming API is part of this pattern(which should be in my view as it is asynchronous) then why there is a separate integration pattern 'UI Update based on data change'listed in doc ? Use case(es) related to this pattern(UI Update based on data change) can be easily met with either platform event or change data capture and can be said to be part of 'fire and forget' pattern. Isn't it?
2. Another solution of this pattern is '**Custom Lightning component or Visualforce page that initiates an Apex SOAP or HTTP asynchronous callout**': if we do call outs from VF/Lightning, then in my view, it should be synchronous? What is example of this kind of scenario? 'Continuation' calls via VF/Lightning page is only I can think as an example here. Is there any thing else to consider?
3. Lastly, another solution is 'Outbound messaging and callbacks'. Under Idempotency it is mentioned '**Using a callback ensures that the data retrieved is at a specific point in time rather than when the message was sent**': This sentence is totally unclear to me. Could someone elaborate. Does that mean, when target system will first receive the message, do the processing at its end, then do callback for further retrieval of data from Salesforce'. How it is benefecial and why Salesforce has stressed on this point?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. [All three event types](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.228.0.api_streaming.meta/api_streaming/event_comparison.htm) - platform, streaming and CDC - are a potential fit for Fire & Forget pattern. Platform events are the best fit because they can be customized (schema/payload) and fired via Apex or other APIs. The F&F [integration pattern](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.integration_patterns_and_practices.meta/integration_patterns_and_practices/integ_pat_remote_process_invocation_fire_forget.htm) doesn't mention CDC and streaming to avoid confusing the reader and make the choice simpler.

The difference between Fire & Forget vs UI Update is the perspective of the event consumer which ultimately boils down to your use case. Producer perspective: asynchronous event publication is architecturally similar in both patterns. Consumer perspective: in F&F, the consumer isn't considered whereas in UI Update the consumer is important.

2. The callout can be synchronous or asynchronous. The pattern explains why in this case the callout should be asynchronous:  *in this pattern, Salesforce doesn’t wait for the request to complete before handing off control to the user*
3. From the Outbound Messaging in F&F pattern

> Idempotency — If an acknowledgment isn’t received in a timely fashion,
> outbound messaging performs retries. Multiple messages can be sent to
> the target system. Using a callback ensures that the data retrieved is
> at a specific point in time rather than when the message was sent.
>
> Callbacks provide a way to mitigate the impacts of out-of-sequence messaging.

They mean that if you do use Outbound Messaging, it can automatically retry and that's an example of an idempotent call. It can be argued that if the state of the domain changes as a result of the callback, it's no longer idempotent. Furthermore, the callback voids the "Forget" portion of F&F. This is an academic point. The explanation of Outbound Messaging as a possible fit for F&F wants you to be aware that it will retry and there's an option of a callback, that's all.